# Folder Copied/Moved/Extracted externally without using Ubuntu Terminal, is not detected/accessed later in ubuntu terminal

Tags: command-line, windows-subsystem-for-linux

With help of Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) I installed Ubuntu Terminal on Windows 10.

Current Work directory in windows: `E:\projects`.

Work directory in where the WSL Ubuntu system is installed:

```
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\home\USER
```

I was trying to transfer some of my previous work from windows environment to Ubuntu. I copied all the folders to `\home\USER\work`. But I'm not able to access that using `ls` command in Ubuntu terminal.

Please see below images.

Here is folder from windows environment:

[image]

Copied to Ubuntu workspace:

[image]

Tried to access using Ubuntu Terminal:

[image]

But unable to access that `xyz` folder.

Comment: Do not copy files from Windows to WSL with copy-paste or Ctrl+C-Ctrl+V. Use `cp` command in WSL to copy files or folders.

Comment: @Biswapriyo how to access Windows files in WSL?

Comment: `C:\` drive translated into `/mnt/c/` by default.

Comment: Can you check the `properties`, `security` of `xyz` in windows?

Comment: @WalterA Yeah, I did. Permissions are set to full control.